# Dynamically resize a Caffeine Cache

Tags: java, caching, caffeine

I am currently migrating from [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap) to [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) and I am stuck on trying to find an equivalent feature of [setCapacity](https://www.toolsverse.com/javadoc/com/toolsverse/util/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.html#setCapacity-long-)

```
  _myCache.setCapacity(newCacheSize);
```

Is there a way to do the same in Caffeine ?

Should I copy my current cache into a newly created one with the new size ? That doesn't seem very efficient but I don't see another way to do so at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These knobs are tucked away under [cache.policy()](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Policy) as they are specific to how the cache was created. This way many messy methods can be provided without complicating the core apis.

```
cache.policy().eviction().ifPresent(eviction -> {
  eviction.setMaximum(newCacheSize);
});
```

Comment: It was indeed tucked away and i didn't see it in the GitHub Wiki, Thank you @Ben Manes